# Como puedo pausar utilizar el metodo sleep en un hilo especifico sin que los demas hilos que tengo se congelen igual?

Tags: java, hilos, javafx, scenebuilder

Mi duda es de como puedo hacer para que en un hilo en especifico que estoy almacenado en una List con varios hilos, poder usar un sleep pero sin que este me afecte a los demas hilos del List, este es el codigo donde estoy generando los hilos y los almaceno:

```
    Hilo hilo1 = new Hilo();
    Hilo hilo2 = new Hilo();
    Hilo hilo3 = new Hilo();

    hilo1.crearVentana("Lista de procesos", "listaProcesos", 5, 5);
    hilo2.crearVentana("Memoria Principal", "memoriaPrincipal", 909, 5);
    hilo3.crearVentana("CPU1", "ejecucionProcesos", 457, 5);
    hilos.add(hilo1);
    hilos.add(hilo2);
    hilos.add(hilo3);
    int x = 5;
    int y = 355;

    if (cantidadCPU > 1) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= cantidadCPU - 1; i++) {
            Hilo newHilo = new Hilo();
            String nombreVentana = "CPU " + (i + 1);
            String fxmlVentana = "ejecucionProcesos";
            int posX = x;
            int posY = y;
            x += 452;

            newHilo.crearVentana(nombreVentana, fxmlVentana, posX, posY);
            hilos.add(newHilo);
        }
    }
    // Iniciar los hilos de las ventanas
    for (Hilo hilo : hilos) {
        hilo.start();
    }
```

Y en este metodo es donde estoy tratando de que el ciclo se ejecute cada segundo, como se puede observar hay una funcion para buscar el hilo al que quiero hacerle el sleep, pero cuando ejecuto el programa y se ejecuta este metodo, se congelan todos los demas hilos. ¿Estoy haciendo algun procedimiento mal?

```
public void ejecutarRoundRobin(EjecucionProcesosController controlador) {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        final int totalFilas = procesosEnCPU.size();
        final int totalColumnas = 20;
        final Hilo hilo = App.obtenerHilo(controlador);
        System.out.println(hilo + " hilo");

        int[] filaActual = {1};
        int[] columnaActual = {1};
        int[] titulo = {0};

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

            pintarCelda(filaActual[0], columnaActual[0]);

            columnaActual[0]++;
            filaActual[0]++;
            titulo[0]++;
            if (filaActual[0] > totalFilas) {
                filaActual[0] = 1;
            }
            System.out.println("pasa");

            try {
                // Detener temporalmente el hilo asociado a 'hilo'
                hilo.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: ¿Es `hilo instanceof Thread`? Si es verdad, entonces `hilo.sleep()` es la misma que `Thread.sleep()`. No hace nada para `hilo`. `sleep` no es un método de instancia. `sleep` literalmente no hace nada. `sleep(1000)` hace nada por 1000 milliseconds, y luego regresa.